# Is HTML 5 good over flash for Developing Animations and Games Compatible on Android and i OS

Tags: ios, html, flash, animation

I have got a work for the Development of the Asp.net website which Contains Animations as well as interactive Games.Now the main focus is the Compatibility issue.What ever Games or animations needs to be designed should be able to run on Computer System browsers as well as on Android and i OS.
After  quick research on Google i got to know that Flash is not supportive on Apple.So i thought to carry forward with HTML 5.So if i carry forward my work with HTML 5 will it be Compatible with Computer systems browser as well as Android and i OS without the need to install flash player plugin.

Which way i should take please Help..

Edit: removed android tag

Comment: @donfuxx: Since you already know that the edit summary goes in its own field, why did you edit the body to include a note anyway?

Comment: @BoltClock because if I just remove the tag (and don't edit anything in the question itself) the "edit at least 6 chars" warning pops up. And I really just wanted to retag the question without formatting the question itself. I am aware about edit summary field ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock just tried on another question adding & removing tags without editing text and worked. dunno why the "edit at least.." msg popped up for me here..

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 is supported on modern browsers on desktops and smartphones, with some features supported to varying degrees across different platforms and browsers.

[Here](http://mobilehtml5.org/) is a useful reference table to see what is supported as a starters guide.